# Call a function when an attribute is attached?

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-attributes

I'm building a website in ASP.net and I've created an attribute which contains Requirements for functions to complete.

Right now I have to have a bit of code at the top of the function to check the requirements(as seen below), and since its the same in every function, I'm wondering if there is a way to automatically call the function UserAction.Rule.IsValid.  I'll also need to be able to pass MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod(), as well as return an enum/int.

Here is my code now.

```
  [UserAction.Rule(UserAction.Rule.RestrictionFailRequirements.RequiresOneRestriction, new int[] { 2, 11 })]
        public static int Login(string loginName, string password)
        {

            if (!UserAction.Rule.IsValid(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()))
                return 4;//User is banned

          //Login stuff.....
        }
```

Edit: I managed to find more info on the subject, and before I had UserAction.Rule deriving from Attribute, instead of the AuthorizeAttribute in the MVC library.

So now that I have changed it to the AuthorizeAttribute it doesn't seem to be calling the OnAuthorization. Do I need to call that in the function I'm trying to use the attribute on?

So my code now looks like this, and in UserAction.Authorize I have overridden OnAuthorization.

```
        [Authorize]
        [UserAction.Authorize(UserAction.Authorize.RestrictionFailRequirements.RequiresOneRestriction, new int[] { 1, 11 })]
        public static int RegisterUser(string regID, string username, string email, string password, string firstname, string lastname)
        {
            //Login stuff.....
        }
```

Comment: I don't understand your current logic, if you're using an Attribute to check things inside the same method, why not use the method directly and pass to it the arguments instead of using an Attribute?

Comment: What you're describing is aspect oriented programming and you'll need an external tool to achieve this. Something like [PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/)

Comment: Haitam, the way I'm getting the  attribute data is with the method, that's why I was needing to pass the method.

I just found some more info so I edited my post.

David do you know if the MVC AuthorizeAttribute can achieve this? Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: [Here's an approach](http://scotthannen.org/blog/2016/03/13/constructor-injection-webapi-actionfilters.html) that I can expand on. You use a global filter, and that filter checks for the presence of an attribute on the controller and/or method that was called. If it finds the attribute it then executes the filter.

Comment: I can't seem to find HttpActionContext Scott, its supposedly in System.Web.Http.Controllers but I can't find it in the package.